# Route one hostname to different root folder using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a main domain for my web hosting account, let's call it `maindomain.com`. I also have a totally different domain which is handled by the same hosting account, let's call it `sub.otherdomain.com`.

The folder structure looks like this:

```
public_html
   .htaccess
   index.php                <-- prints "maindomain.com index.php"
   test.php                 <-- prints "maindomain.com test.php"
   sub.otherdomain.com
      index.php             <-- prints "sub.otherdomain.com index.php"
      test.php              <-- prints "sub.otherdomain.com test.php"
      test
          index.php         <-- prints "sub.otherdomain.com test/index.php"
          test.php          <-- prints "sub.otherdomain.com test/test.php"
```

Now, as you can imagine, I want all requests for anything under `sub.otherdomain.com` to go to the folder `/sub.otherdomain.com`.

So in my `.htaccess` I put

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.otherdomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ sub.otherdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [END]
```

It seems to work as long as I end the URL with a slash and don't provide a filename, but not otherwise...

```
These are working okay
------------------------
Url: https://sub.otherdomain.com/
Expected output: "sub.otherdomain.com index.php"
Actual output:   "sub.otherdomain.com index.php" 

Url: https://sub.otherdomain.com/test/
Expected output: "sub.otherdomain.com test/index.php"
Actual output:   "sub.otherdomain.com test/index.php" 



The rest don't work
-------------------
Url: https://sub.otherdomain.com/test.php
Expected output: "sub.otherdomain.com test.php"
Actual output:   "File not found"

Url: https://sub.otherdomain.com/index.php
Expected output: "sub.otherdomain.com index.php"
Actual output:   "maindomain.com index.php"

Url: https://sub.otherdomain.com/test/test.php
Expected output: "sub.otherdomain.com test/test.php"
Actual output:   "maindomain.com test.php"
```

I tried different variations of the `.htaccess` file, but none work the way I expect it to.

Even if I try

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.otherdomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule . sub.otherdomain.com/test.php [END]
```

I get the output

```
"maindomain.com test.php"
```

It's as if `.htaccess` is not invoked at all if I specify a file that actually exists...

Comment: Have a try switching off content negotiation in your http server.

Comment: Also test with a non-PHP file, eg. `test.html`. "It's as if `.htaccess` is not invoked at all if I specify a file that actually exists..." - This can happen for a couple of reasons. **1.** The way PHP installed, eg. requests for `.php` files are proxied to the backend PHP engine (CGI). Testing a non-PHP file would clarify this. **2.** There is a front-end proxy server that serves your static assets. Check the HTTP response headers for such a request. However, this does not explain the 1st and 3rd examples which "don't work"?

Comment: To clarify, both these hostnames point to the same document root (ie. `public_html` in your file structure)? You have no other directives in your `.htaccess` file (or server config)? Ideally you would change the document root for this alternative hostname/subdomain using either the hosting control panel (eg. cPanel) or in the server config - I assume this is not an option? What version of Apache are you using?

Comment: @MrWhite It seems to be because of how PHP is set up by this hosting provider. I've been using a different one for 10 years and not experienced anything like this, but this new one seems to have a lot of "weird" custom configurations, including their own custom control panel which is quite simple compared to cPanel. I gave up on trying to work around their limitations using `.htaccess` and just upgraded the account to have two proper domains with their own separate file structures registered instead.